# Samsun Galaxy S6 USB host and Charging

Tags: android, usb, host, samsung-galaxy

I'd like to be able to use my S6 as a USB host and charge the phone a the same time.

With the Note 2 you could put a 68K resistor between the ID Sense pin and GND on the USB OTG cable which would configure the phone as a USB host and enable charging but this no longer seems to be the case with the S6.

I have experimented with resistor values at 5K increments from 20K to 150K but with no success, although 55K puts the phone into some sort of VR (??) mode. Charging is enabled at nearly all of these values but the phone does not enter USB host mode.

Other research has suggested that this feature may have been removed since the S5 but it may be possible to enable it by modifying the kernel but I have been unable to find a custom ROM that advertises this as a feature.

So my questions are:

1) Has anyone managed to enable USB host mode with charging? (Stock or custom ROM)

2) What part of the kernel is responsible for managing this or is this a dead end?

Comment: `55K puts the phone into some sort of VR ` very interesting!!

Comment: Finally, did you find a solution? I am in the same process

Comment: Sort of, I end up modifying the kernel so that when in USB host mode it required power to be provided. Breaks the USB spec but for what I needed this wasn’t an issue